# serving my views(.html) files also via asset pipelining

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

Recently i upgraded to rails 3.2 and am using the asset pipelining feature which is working fine for my javascripts and css.All of these files i am serving from app/assets.

Now my html files are in public/tpl. I want to include and serve them also via asset ppelining such that all the html files are also served as a single file.

I read a lot about this and found that i can use JST for the purpose. I was trying to rename my .html files to .jst files and put them under app/assets/templates. I thought the JST which convert them and thus will be served as a single file.

But i am getting errors saying:
Syntax error.
When i looked for it in application.js i found that the JST parser is trying to convert them into jst but not able to do so properly.

Is my approach correct, If yes then what should i do , if not what is the best way to do the job.any pointers?

Thanks,
Ankur

Answer (score 1):

I would look into using a gem which adds handlers. For example there is [`handlebars_assets`](https://github.com/leshill/handlebars_assets) for handlebars (`.hbs`), [`hogan_assets`](https://github.com/leshill/hogan_assets) for plain mustache templates, [`haml_coffee_assets`](https://github.com/netzpirat/haml_coffee_assets) for haml+coffeescript, and so on.

Comment: i think cloudedit is also doing the same thing. But if i am using the .jst files and including them in my application.js i am getting syntax error? any pointers?

Comment: Well, what is in the `.jst` files? They need to be compilable and so on... it's best to use a proper asset pipeline handling gem and put the files in `app/assets` as prescribed. I'm not sure what 'cloudedit' is or how it relates to this.